# How is exif info encoded?

Tags: java, image-processing, exif

Greetings,

I'm going to get exif info from some images using android. I know there are some standard java lib's out there that I could use with the device. I'm sure I will end up using one.

But in the meantime can someone explain to me how this information is encoded inside a JPG?  Where / how would you usually get the info from the document. When I opent he document up with a text editor its all binary.

Curious as to how it works and how I could potentially read the data in question.

Comment: Here is an article I wrote a while ago: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ExifLibrary.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you search for the string "Exif" you will find the start of the Exif data -- it's quite complicated, and I would recommend using a library -- (e.g. my company's [DotImage](http://atalasoft.com/products/dotimage) if you were using .NET).

Here's a high level description though:

The Exif itself is inside of an AppMarker -- the three bytes before will be E1 (AppMarker 1) and the size of the marker's data in the endianness of the file. Two bytes after the Exif you will see the endianness marker (e.g. `49 49` means `II` which means Intel, little endian -- that means that 2 bytes numbers have the low byte first in the file).

The rest of the data uses offsets extensively, the offset is from the location of the first endian byte (the 49 in the above case)

8 bytes from this offset is a 2-byte number which is the number of exif tags.  If you are in `II` byte order, reverse the bytes to read the length.

Then there will be this number of 12 byte records.  Each one is:

```
2 bytes: Tag ID
2 bytes: Tag Type
4 bytes: Length
4 bytes: data if the data is 4 bytes or less, or an offset to the data
```

After the N 12 byte records, you will have the data pointed to by each offset used in the above N records.  You need to look up ids and types to see what they mean and how they are represented.

Comment: **"Data if the data is 4 bytes or less, or an offset to the data"** is very important, because most sites suggest that it's only an offset.

Answer (score 19):

I'm a bit late to the party, but having written a [Java library for processing Exif](http://drewnoakes.com/code/exif/) (among other types of metadata) I thought I'd chime in.

### Exif

Exif is built upon *TIFF*, the Tagged Image File Format. So we first have to examine TIFF:

- A TIFF document contains multiple *directories* known as IFDs (Image File Directories)
- Each IFD contains zero or more *tags*
- IFDs may link to zero or more other IFDs
- Each tag has a numeric ID and contains zero or more values of a specified data type

Think of the structure as a tree with primitive values at the leaves. TIFF is self describing about its structure, but it doesn't dictate anything about what the values at the leaves actually *mean*.

Really you can store any kind of data in TIFF, it's not coupled to images.

The TIFF file has a generic header:

- *2 bytes* for byte ordering, either `MM` or `II` in ASCII. This tells you what order to consider all the future bytes in -- LSB or MSB first.
- *2 bytes* TIFF marker, for Exif this is `0x002A`
- *4 bytes* pointer to first IFD

IFDs have equally simple structure:

- *2 bytes* for the number of tags to follow
- *N bytes* for the tags themselves (where N = 12 * tagCount)
- *4 bytes* for optional pointer to next IFD (use zero value if no IFD is linked)

Tags have a simple representation in 12 bytes:

- *2 bytes* for the tag ID
- *2 bytes* for the data type (int8u, int16s, float, etc)
- *4 bytes* for the number of data values of the specified type
- *4 bytes* for the value itself, if it fits, otherwise for a pointer to another location where the data may be found -- this could be a pointer to the beginning of another IFD

The data types are predefined. For example: 1 represents 8-bit unsigned integers, and 12 represents 64-bit floating point numbers.

So with all that you can go ahead and follow the data file. Some observations:

- You cannot read the data in order, as it is free to link all over the place. You must either have random access, or else synthesize it by buffering.
- All you know at this point is that a tag with ID `0x1234` has 4 integers: `{1,2,3,4}`

To decode TIFF into Exif, you need to apply the dictionary that defines what each IFD represents, and what each tag ID within those IFDs represent.

### JPEG

Most users of my library are processing JPEG files. JPEGs have a completely different structure, comprising a sequence of segments. Each segment has an identifier and a block of bytes. Exif is found in the `APP1` (numeric value `0xe1`) segment of a JPEG file. Once you have that, you must skip past a few leading bytes (`Exif\0\0`) before seeing the `MM` or `II` that denote the start of the TIFF formatted Exif data.

### Bringing it all together with an example

Here's a binary dump of one of my library's [sample images](http://code.google.com/p/metadata-extractor/wiki/ImageDatabase):

[image]

In order:

#### JPEG Starts

- `FF D8` is the JPEG 'magic number'.
- `FF` marks a JPEG segment start.
- `E1` indicates the JPEG segment type (this is `APP1`, where Exif lives).
- `18 B3` (6,323 decimal) gives the length of the segment (including the size bytes), so we know that all the Exif data for this JPG file will sit within the next 6,321 bytes. Note that in JPG, multi-byte values are encoded with Motorolla ordering, although nested Exif data may use Intel ordering.
- `45 78 69 66 00 00` or in ASCII `Exif\0\0` is the Exif preamble. `APP1` is not exclusively reseved for Exif, so this discriminates.

#### TIFF/Exif Starts

- `4D 4D` or `MM` indicates we have Motorolla byte order in this Exif block
- `00 2A` is our standard TIFF marker, as discussed above
- `00 00 00 08` is the offset (8 bytes) to the first IFD, relative to the TIFF header (`MM` in this case). This points directly to the next byte in the sequence in this case, though it doesn't have to.

#### IFD Starts

- `00 08` opens our first IFD and tells we'll have 8 tags coming up

#### Tag Starts

- `01 0F` is the ID for the first tag in the first IFD, in this case the manufacturer of the camera
- `00 02` is the type of the value (2 means it's an ASCII string)
- `00 00 00 16` is the number of components, meaning we'll have a 22-byte string
- `00 00 01 B2` (434 decimal) is a pointer to the location of that string, relative to the TIFF header (`MM`). You can't see it in this screenshot, but it points to `45 41 53 54 4D 41 4E 20 4B 4F 44 41 4B 20 43 4F 4D 50 41 4E 59 00` which is `EASTMAN KODAK COMPANY` in ASCII

### RAW

Camera raw files (CR2/NEF/ORW...) generally use TIFF, however they mostly use different tags to those for Exif. The second pair of bytes in these files will be different to `00 2A` as well, indicating the type of TIFF dictionary that ought to be applied.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXIF#Technical) has a few pointers on how and where exactly EXIF data is stored in a file. Of course, there's always the [standard](http://www.digicamsoft.com/exif22/exif22/html/exif22_1.htm?gInitialPosX=10px&gInitialPosY=10px&gZoomValue=100) itself to read up.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty tedious to parse EXIF data but you can find many libraries to parse it. My favorite one for Java is,

<strike>http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/Web-Server/Jigsaw/org/w3c/tools/jpeg/Exif.java.htm</strike>

http://jigsaw.w3.org/

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the good libraries for Java and EXIF: http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

Comment: Thanks for teh link. I've come across a number of libraries. Was curious as to how it works :-)